# Realm & Kotlin access field in variable

Tags: java, android, gson, realm

I am having the following situation:

I am getting some data via Retrofit2 & GSON that I dont want to save completely in the realm database. But i need to access the model later on.

Well here is the model:

```
open class Notification() : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey var pushNotificationId: Long = -1
    var date: Date = Date()

    var apsRaw: String = ""
    @Ignore var aps: Aps? = null
        get() = field ?: Gson.getInstance().fromJson(apsRaw, Aps::class.java)
        private set
```

with

```
open class Aps(var message: String = "",
               var category: String = "")
```

What i want to achieve is, to save the `apsRaw` string in realm only (*to avoid having another table 'Aps'*) but during runtime i want to use the `Aps` instance for convenience reasons. So when loading it from realm i would like to initialize it if it has not been initialized before.

This way i am calling the Gson converter every time because the access to realm via `field` always returns `null`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
@Ignore var aps: Aps? = null
    get() {
        if(field == null && "" != appsRaw) {
            field = Gson.getInstance().fromJson(apsRaw, Aps::class.java)
        }
        return field
    }
    private set
```

Comment: well, field still will be always `null` in the getter due to realm magic

Comment: Why would it be? It's an ignored field.

Comment: Arrrr. you are right.. i completely forgot to assign the "field" to avoid re-gson-izing.